# Sorting the y-axis of a seaborn lmplot based on duration

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization

I have the following dataset extract which I am trying to use to plot a seaborn lmplot.

```
Case_ID Activity    Timestamp   Cum_Duration
0   1   a   2016-04-15 08:41:28 0.0
1   1   b   2016-04-18 12:55:01 3.0
2   1   d   2016-04-19 07:22:59 4.0
3   1   e   2016-04-23 15:06:58 8.0
4   1   f   2016-04-24 19:18:32 9.0
5   1   g   2016-04-25 14:56:42 10.0
6   1   h   2016-04-26 10:00:36 11.0
7   2   a   2016-04-18 20:40:14 0.0
8   2   b   2016-04-21 22:42:39 3.0
9   2   d   2016-04-24 01:29:27 5.0
10  2   g   2016-04-25 22:36:27 7.0
11  2   e   2016-04-27 16:12:28 9.0
12  2   f   2016-04-28 15:00:35 10.0
13  2   h   2016-05-01 18:32:18 13.0
14  3   a   2016-04-27 01:45:07 0.0
15  3   b   2016-04-27 21:50:32 1.0
16  3   d   2016-04-29 00:12:15 2.0
17  3   g   2016-04-29 16:24:46 3.0
18  3   e   2016-04-30 22:57:03 4.0
19  3   f   2016-05-02 01:33:30 5.0
20  3   h   2016-05-02 11:06:53 5.0
21  4   a   2016-05-02 08:38:34 0.0
22  4   b   2016-05-06 00:50:31 4.0
23  4   d   2016-05-06 17:56:11 4.0
24  4   g   2016-05-13 10:34:23 11.0
25  4   e   2016-05-13 13:56:10 11.0
26  4   f   2016-05-14 23:42:03 13.0
27  4   h   2016-05-17 14:02:28 15.0
28  5   a   2016-05-09 07:17:12 0.0
29  5   b   2016-05-10 06:29:42 1.0
30  5   c   2016-05-11 05:04:34 2.0
```

So I have plotted the following graph using the following code.

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.set_context('talk')
relactivity_plot = sns.lmplot(x='Cum_Duration',y='Case_ID', data=rdoa_plot, hue='Activity',height=10, aspect=1.5,fit_reg=False, scatter_kws={'s':150, 'alpha':1.0})
relactivity_plot.set(ylim=(max(rdoa_plot['Case_ID'])+1,0), yticks=(rdoa_plot['Case_ID']).unique(), xlim=(0, max(rdoa_plot['Cum_Duration'])+1))
relactivity_plot.fig.suptitle('Analyzing events timeline for the first 20 events')
```

[Seaborn plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yoN6.png)

However, I would love to sort the y-axis according to the cumulative duration such that the cases with the shortest time are at the top and the cases with the longer duration are shown below such as this graph.

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHQ2g.png)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the 'Case_ID' column to strings, then calculate their order via pandas `groupby()` and use that order as to make 'Case_ID' categorical.

Here is some example code. (I renamed `rdoa_plot` to `rdoa_df` as the name confused me. I also used the `scatterplot` directly, as the `lmplot` seemed to be reduced to only scatter dots in the example.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''Case_ID Activity    Timestamp   Cum_Duration
0   1   a   "2016-04-15 08:41:28" 0.0
1   1   b   "2016-04-18 12:55:01" 3.0
2   1   d   "2016-04-19 07:22:59" 4.0
3   1   e   "2016-04-23 15:06:58" 8.0
4   1   f   "2016-04-24 19:18:32" 9.0
5   1   g   "2016-04-25 14:56:42" 10.0
6   1   h   "2016-04-26 10:00:36" 11.0
7   2   a   "2016-04-18 20:40:14" 0.0
8   2   b   "2016-04-21 22:42:39" 3.0
9   2   d   "2016-04-24 01:29:27" 5.0
10  2   g   "2016-04-25 22:36:27" 7.0
11  2   e   "2016-04-27 16:12:28" 9.0
12  2   f   "2016-04-28 15:00:35" 10.0
13  2   h   "2016-05-01 18:32:18" 13.0
14  3   a   "2016-04-27 01:45:07" 0.0
15  3   b   "2016-04-27 21:50:32" 1.0
16  3   d   "2016-04-29 00:12:15" 2.0
17  3   g   "2016-04-29 16:24:46" 3.0
18  3   e   "2016-04-30 22:57:03" 4.0
19  3   f   "2016-05-02 01:33:30" 5.0
20  3   h   "2016-05-02 11:06:53" 5.0
21  4   a   "2016-05-02 08:38:34" 0.0
22  4   b   "2016-05-06 00:50:31" 4.0
23  4   d   "2016-05-06 17:56:11" 4.0
24  4   g   "2016-05-13 10:34:23" 11.0
25  4   e   "2016-05-13 13:56:10" 11.0
26  4   f   "2016-05-14 23:42:03" 13.0
27  4   h   "2016-05-17 14:02:28" 15.0
28  5   a   "2016-05-09 07:17:12" 0.0
29  5   b   "2016-05-10 06:29:42" 1.0
30  5   c   "2016-05-11 05:04:34" 2.0'''
rdoa_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)
rdoa_df['Case_ID'] = rdoa_df['Case_ID'].astype(str)
df_max_dur = rdoa_plot.groupby('Case_ID')['Cum_Duration'].max().sort_values()
case_id_order = df_max_dur.index.astype(str)
rdoa_df['Case_ID'] = pd.Categorical(rdoa_df['Case_ID'], categories=case_id_order)

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.set_context('talk')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
sns.scatterplot(x='Cum_Duration', y='Case_ID', data=rdoa_df, hue='Activity', s=500, alpha=1, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, max(rdoa_df['Cum_Duration']) + 0.5)
ax.set_ylim(len(case_id_order) - 0.5, -0.5)
for s in ax.spines:
    ax.spines[s].set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot ordered by max duration]

To have the activities ordered alphabetically, you could add `hue_order=np.unique(rdoa_df['Activity'])`.

Comment: Thanks so much @JohanC. Really grateful. Please where can I read more about `spines` you used?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/spines.html